# Cannot set properties of null (setting '_closeInteractionType') at _closeDialogVia dialog.mjs

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuvsO.jpg)

After migrated to application's material to 15 version, the  matdialog (built-in close button) is not working and throwing below error:

> - `ERROR TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting '_closeInteractionType')
> - at _closeDialogVia (dialog.mjs:476:30)
> - at MatLegacyDialogClose._onButtonClick (legacy-dialog.mjs:287:24)
> - at MatLegacyDialogClose_click_HostBindingHandler (legacy-dialog.mjs:291:107)
> - at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.mjs:14037:16)
> - at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.mjs:14070:22)
> - at HTMLButtonElement. (platform-browser.mjs:455:38)
> - at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:443:35)
> - at core.mjs:23946:55
> - at AsyncStackTaggingZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:23946:36)
> - at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:442:64)
> - `

Attached image.

After executed the command :

- `ng generate @angular/material:mdc-migration`

`***Parent.compoment.ts***`

```
- import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
- public dialog: MatDialog
- 
- const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EmailOptionComponent, {
- role: 'dialog',
- disableClose: true,
- panelClass: ['fis-style', 'panel-export-width', 'margin_35px']
-     });
- dialogRef.componentInstance.emailInputOptions = this.emailOptionsData;
- dialogRef.componentInstance.pageName = 'GAIN_LOSS_PAGE';
- dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
- if (result) {
- this.EmailSend();
-       }
-     });
-
```

`***email-options.component.ts***`

```
- 
- `constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EmailOptionComponent>, private emailSandbox: EmailSandbox, private store: Store<any>) { }
- 
- 
-  confirmDialog = () => {
- this.dialogRef.close(true);
-     }``
```

the above code is not working. It should work without throwing any errors

Answer (score 8):

I also faced this issue, and you are correct: the reason is the migration to the new `mat-mdc` API.

This error is thrown when you close your `MatDialog` with the `MatLegacyDialog` `close()` method or with the `MatLegacyDialogClose` directive, instead of using the new `mdc` API for those.

It also occours on the inverse way, when you use `MatLegacyDialog` and trying to close it with the `close()` method of the `MatDialog` API, or with the `MatDialogClose` directive, instead of using the `Legacy` API.

Bottom line is - keep using the same version of mat-dialog, legacy or the new one, for all diffrent operations related to it.

I'm very curious if it solved your problem. please let me know!!

Answer (score 0):

it's very difficult to read the code without format, there's an option to post it properly.
It seems to be no opened Dialog to close.
You can trigger the close event from child to parent like that:

child ts:

```
import { EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
    export class MyChildComponent {
    @Output() onCloseDialog: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();
      
    // ...
}
```

child html:

```
<button (click)="onCloseDialog.emit(true)">Close dialog</button>
```

parent html:

```
<app-my-child (onCloseDialog)="closeDialog($event)"></app-my-child>
```

parent ts:

```
closeDialog($event: boolean) {
  if ($event) {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```